# other app 404 status with default app in tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7

I have deployed two app in tomcat webapps dir.And added these config in server.xml:

```
<Context path="" docBase="portal" debug="0" reloadable="true" crossContext="true"/>
<Context path="/admin" docBase="admin" debug="0" reloadable="true" crossContext="true"/>
```

with these config.The portal app  is normal,but I have failed to access admin app with these url:

```
http://localhost:9080/ ->portal app
http://localhost:9080/admin -> admin app  .[all is http 404]
```

so what config is right with this demand.
Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

OK,no people help me.
I have solved this problem myself.
Just add :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>portal.root</param-value>
</context-param>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>admin.root</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in every webapplication web.xml .